# Criteria to SUM if cell above is blank

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get a sum of column values in a Google Spreadsheet only if there is no value in the column above. Consider the following example:

```
       A | B | C
  ---------------------------------
         |   | Formula on blank row
  Apple  | 1 |
  Apple2 | 2 |
         |   |
  Bravo  | 3 |
  Bravo2 | 5 |
```

The sum of `A` should return (1 + 3) which is `4`.

I tried to use the following function in C1:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B,"<>"&"",A1:A)
```

This returns `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was using the SUMIF formula wrong. This works:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A,"",B2:B)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with using closed ranges, try:

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(if(B2:B100="", offset(B2:B100,1,0),0)))
```

Comment: Interesting function, offset. Unfortunately, this formula equals 3, and not 4. I do think this is the right strategy, though. I will work with this equation a bit.

Comment: If you have row 1 blank, start your range from there..  =sum(ArrayFormula(if(B1:B100="", offset(B1:B100,1,0),0)))